# How to select the distinct prefix substrings of a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column of code number. These code no. have 7 digits/char and may compose of both alphanumeric characters and numbers. The last three char of the codeno. always differ from each other but the first four characters which I call prefix can be the same for a number of codeno. but also differ with other. Basically what I want to get are the different format/type of prefix.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(code, 1, 4)
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `left` with `distinct`:

```
select distinct left(code,4)
from yourtable
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c62a/1)